# Redirecting/rewriting wildcard domains to ssl in nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, subdomain, wildcard

I have tried all the solutions found on this site and others but am still having a problem with redirecting a wildcard subdomain with http to https.  I still end up with

```
https://%2A.example.com/site_admin
```

The above url displays in Chrome and "This page can not be displayed" in IE and "Your connection is not private" from chrome on my phone.

The non-wildcard nginx server blocks work fine.

I have tried rewrite and redirect 301 in the server block for the http wildcards, but it still rewrites the url to %A2 (the *).  I think the default server is using the server_name of *.example.com but even when using $host it still rewrites as the *.  Is there another directive that needs to be included?

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    # tell users to go to SSL version this time
    if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
       rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    ## ssl and locations not shown
}

server {
    listen  80;
    server_name manager.example.com ;

    # tell users to go to SSL version this time
    if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
       rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name manager.example.com ;

    ## ssl and locations not shown
}

server {
    listen  80 default_server;
    server_name *.example.com "" ;

    # tell users to go to SSL version this time
    if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
        rewrite     ^   https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        #rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

}
server {
    listen 443  default_server;
    server_name *.example.com ;

    ssl on;
    ## other ssl and locations not shown
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of general nginx misunderstanding/bad practices in there. You should simply be using `$host`. It's somewhat bewildering why you wouldn't just use `server { listen 80 default_server; return 301 https://$host$request_uri; }` (or very similar) to replace all three of your http server blocks.

Comment: Yes I was wondering about the if statement testing for ssl_protocol. I'll change to the return 301.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be the browser cache.  Once it was cleared the redirects worked.  Sometimes it is the simplest thing.

Comment: Thanks @AllanD I had the same issue with `%2A` appearing in my subdomain redirect and it turned out to be a Chrome cache issue.  You should probably accept this answer as your solution.

Comment: You've gotta whatch out with this config as the `$host` header can be easily spoofed and nginx will respect it  

`curl -L -H 'Host: google.com' subdomain.yourdomain.local`

Using host for it is totally fine in dev but I would advise not to use `$host` in production.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the actual `ssl` statement in what is supposed to be a wildcard ssl `server {}` block, thus you actually have a http on 443 port instead of https.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying different things and used "ssl on" instead of ssl in the listen directive as I though it may interfere with the default_server and forgot to show it.  Just edited.   The browser actually redirects to https it just does not pass the host correctly.